# Как правильно осуществить взаимодействие между абстрактным и наследуемыми классами в JAVA?

Tags: java

Всем добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой при решении задачи, суть которой в осуществлении правильного взаимодействия между классами: запутался в прописании методов. Прошу Вашей помощи! Вот условия задачи:
Создаю абстрактный класс Account с тремя методами. Добавляю классы Сберегательный, Кредитный, Расчетный (SavingsAccount, CreditAccount, CheckingAccount соответственно) как потомков класса Счет. В них переопределяю методы. Каждый из них должен хранить баланс. Со сберегательного счета нельзя платить, только переводить и пополнять. Также сберегательный не может уходить в минус. Кредитный не может иметь положительный баланс – если платить с него, то уходит в минус, чтобы вернуть в 0, надо пополнить его. Расчетный может выполнять все три операции, но не может уходить в минус.
Нужно продемонстрировать работу счетов. Также создать три переменные типа Account и присвоить им три разных типа счетов. Большинство методов оставил незаполненными.
Вот мой код:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected int amount;
    protected int balance;

    public Account(int amount, int balance) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    void pay(int amount) { }

    void transfer(Account account, int amount) { }

    void addMoney(int amount) { }
}
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    public SavingsAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        super.pay(amount);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        if (balance -= amount) {
            System.out.println("Баланс не может быть отрицательным!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}
public class CreditAccount extends Account {
    public CreditAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        super.pay(amount);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        super.transfer(account, amount);
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    public CheckingAccount(int amount, int balance) {
        super(amount, balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        super.pay(amount);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        super.transfer(account, amount);
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        super.addMoney(amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал по другому. Попробуйте так

```
public abstract class Account {
    private int amount;
    private int balance;

    public Account(int amount, int balance) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getAmount() { return this.amount;}
    void setAmount(int amount) { this.amount = amount;}  
  // getter setter для баланса
}

// реализуйте интерфейсы Pay,Transfer, Add для каждого класса

public class SavingsAccount extends Account implements Pay,Transfer, Add {

}

public class CheckingAccount extends Account implements Pay,Transfer, Add {

}


public class CreditAccount extends Account implements Pay,Transfer, Add {

}
```

Реализуйте только нужные интерфейсы для ваших классов и почитайте принципы SOLID.
Почитайте повнимательней принцип постановки Liskov. Почитав его вы поймете что не надо плодить классы если нет в них необходимости.

Comment: Без фанатизма. Если к примеру каждый аккаунт может делать трансфер и пополнять баланс, то разбивать не особо есть смысл. Заменить абстрактный класс на интрефейс в целом норм идея если там нет никакой общей логики. Но если конечно будут классы в которых может какого-то метода не быть, то вы абсолютно правы

Comment: Тут нет фанатизма. Interface segregation only.

Comment: Ну ок. Когда таких методов 3 это ок. А если там будет их больше? Если вместо одного класса на 500 строк создать 50 классов по 10 строк, проект не станет лучше работать и читаться. Если есть ситуации в которых могут быть отдельные методы transfer и add то ваше суждение абсолютно верно, в противном случае это не имеет смысла. А заготоавливать на потом если вы не уверены что это необходимо тоже неверно. Это же говорит и Дядюшка Боб

Comment: Это конкретный пример. В ваше случае возможно 500 срок и лучше. Это всё исходя из задачи. У автора классы именно различаются по методам не только по поведению. А так у меня тоже есть классы на 5 000 строк, но это скорее исключения чем правило. Всё зависит от постановки задачи.

Comment: Вот я о том и говорил. Все от задачи зависит-) Просто я к тому, что это стоит пояснить. А то у новичка может сложиться впечатление что стоит плодить классы по 1 методу в количестве 100500=)

Comment: Да если почитать прицип подстановки Liskov. То наследовать про100 так желание пропадает

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что если у вас есть какой-то счет с которого нельзя что-то делать, то это явный признак того, что их нужно разбить.

Ну конечно можно к примеру в вашем сберегательном счете переопределить метод `pay()` который будет бросать `Exception` или что-то вроде того, но это очень плохая практика. Вы можете создать родительский класс вроде такого:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected int balance;

    public Account(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    abstract void transfer(Account account, int amount);

    abstract void addMoney(int amount);
}
```

Если базовый класс не задает никакого общего поведения для наследников, то методы лучше сделать абстрактными.

И интерфейс:

```
interface Payment {

    void pay(int amount);
}
```

В каждом из наследников переопределить методы, например так:

```
public class CreditAccount extends Account implements Payment {
    public CreditAccount(int balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    void pay(int amount) {
        balance = balance - amount; // возможно тут более сложная логика может быть
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        account.addMoney(amount);
        balance = balance - amount; // тут может быть какая-то логика по обработке лимитов кредитки
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        if(balance + amount > 0) {
            // обработать ситуацию когда больше пополнять нельзя. Может быть вернуть остаток или запретить операцию
        } else {
            balance = balance + amount
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
    public SavingsAccount(int balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    void transfer(Account account, int amount) {
        account.addMoney(amount);
        if (balance < amount) {
            // обработать ошибку - недостаточно средств
        } else {
            balance = balance - amount; // тут может быть какая-то логика по обработке лимитов кредитки
        }
    }

    @Override
    void addMoney(int amount) {
        balance = balance + amount
    }
}
```

Это в общих чертах, но выглядеть должно примерно так. Конечно можно вместо интерфейса сделать еще один абстрактный класс который будет наследоваться от `Account` и в нем будет метод `pay()` назвать его к примеру `PaymentAccount`. И сберегательный счет будет наследоваться от `Account` а кредитный и расчетный будут от `PaymentAccount`, но если в этом нет необходимости то всегда стоит предпочитать интерфейсы абстрактным классам.

P.S. Я не совсем понял в чем разница полей `amount` и `balance`, поэтому оставил только одно. Но от этого суть не меняется.